# Конвертация SFLOAT в double

Tags: c, bluetooth

Добрый вечер. Пишу кросс-клиент для BTLE железки. 
Впервые столкнулся с форматом поля SFLOAT.

Кусок из стандарта:

> The following information is defined in ISO/IEEE Std. 
>   11073-2060™1-2008 [1]. The SFLOAT-Type data type is defined to 
>   represent numeric values that are not integer in type. The 
>   SFLOAT-Type is defined as a 16-bit value with 12-bit mantissa  and
>   4-bit exponent. See Annex F.8 of [1] for a thorough  definition of the
>   SFLOAT-Type. This data type is defined as  follows: Exponent Mantissa
>   Size 4 bit 12 bit
>
> 16-bit float type; the integer type is a placeholder only
>
> SFLOAT-Type ::= INT-U16 The 16–bit value contains a 4-bit  exponent to
>   base 10, followed by a 12-bit mantissa.  Each is in twos-complement
>   form. Special values are assigned to  express the following:  NaN
>   [exponent 0, mantissa +(2^11 –1) → 0x07FF]  NRes [exponent 0, mantissa
>   –(2^11) → 0x0800] 
>   + INFINITY [exponent 0, mantissa +(2^11 –2) → 0x07FE]  – INFINITY [exponent 0, mantissa –(2^11 –2) → 0x0802]  Reserved for future use
>   [exponent 0, mantissa –(2^11 –1) → 0x0801]

На просторах сети был найден (https://github.com/signove/antidote/blob/master/src/util/bytelib.c) нужный код и немного обрезан под мои нужды:

```
typedef enum {
    MDER_S_POSITIVE_INFINITY = 0x07FE,
    MDER_S_NaN = 0x07FF,
    MDER_S_NRes = 0x0800,
    MDER_S_RESERVED_VALUE = 0x0801,
    MDER_S_NEGATIVE_INFINITY = 0x0802
} ReservedSFloatValues;
static const quint32 FIRST_S_RESERVED_VALUE = MDER_S_POSITIVE_INFINITY;

static const double reserved_float_values[5] = {INFINITY, NAN, NAN, NAN, -INFINITY};

double read_sfloat(quint16 int_data)
{
    quint16 mantissa = int_data & 0x0FFF;
    quint8 expoent = int_data >> 12;

    if (expoent >= 0x0008) {
        expoent = -((0x000F + 1) - expoent);
    }

    float output = 0;

    if (mantissa >= FIRST_S_RESERVED_VALUE && mantissa
            <= MDER_S_NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
        output = reserved_float_values[mantissa - FIRST_S_RESERVED_VALUE];
    } else {
        if (mantissa >= 0x0800) {
            mantissa = -((0x0FFF + 1) - mantissa);
        }
        double magnitude = pow(10.0f, expoent);
        output = (mantissa * magnitude);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Есть контрольные данные из спека к прибору:

> Byte:2 Format:SFLOAT,  LittleEndian
>
> ex.1) 17.6Kpa -> 0xB0, 0xF0 ex.2)
>   128mmHg -> 0x80, 0x00

Прогонка первого ex. через парсер — результат inf. Второго — 128 OK

Не совсем понимаю, где я закопался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экспонента должна иметь знаковый тип.

```
qint16 mantissa = int_data & 0x0FFF;
qint8 expoent = int_data >> 12;
```